# Polymorphic engines in C and/or C++

Tags: c++, c, assembly, encryption, obfuscation

I stumbled across polymorphic engines and I don't know anything about them. However, I am curious about how they are written. Every example that I've looked up writes them in assembly, my assembly is not good at all; I know just a few instructions here and there but not that well. On the other hand, I am good in C and C++.

I am familiar with the concept of polymorphism in C++ but after reading about polymorphic engines, I am assuming that they are different from the polymorphism in C++.

I'm just looking for simple code that shows encryption/decryption and/or obfuscation of code using C and/or C++

How can techniques such as using virtual keyword in C++ be used to obfuscate or encrypt the code in an application?

NOTE: I was told to transfer this question from stackoverflow.com to this place.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723085/polymorphic-engines-in-c-or-c If you believe your question is a better fit at other site, flag it for moderator to migrate

Comment: i wasn't aware of the procedure

Comment: A polymorphic engine is a tool that creates your binary in any of a number of arbitrarily different-seeming versions (like some viruses do to escape signature-based filtering). Just thought I'd add that for the sake of people like me,who had never heard of one.

Comment: @KilianFoth  is it possible to write this sorta engine in C/C++?

Comment: Sure. After all, compilers are written in C, much of the time. It's just another level of complexity on top of an already formidable tool chain, so you'll probably not get a useful answer in the format possible here.

Comment: I see, i'll keep doing more research, lastly, would it be better to write engines in C? or is assembly the best choice?

Comment: Polymorphic engines are primarily used in viruses to beat the virus detection software installed on the machine. As such the are confined to assembly in order to perform loops and other operations in novel fashion that the virus detector won't be looking out for. You probably aren't going to get any real world examples in C or C++ since by definition they are using common easily recognized methods for performing an action (a for loop in C will be outputted to assembly in a very recognizable fashion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am familiar with the concept of polymorphism in C++ but after
> reading about polymorphic engines, I am assuming that they are
> different from the polymorphism in C++.
>
> How can techniques such as using virtual keyword in C++ be used to
> obfuscate or encrypt the code in an application?

Your assumption is correct. They are different things.

- Typically, neither C nor C++ make use of run-time code generation, nor do they use any self-modifying code.
- C and C++ allows function pointers, as well as unchecked type casts between pretty much anything. These two features allow one to make a CPU jump (execution transfer) into any address.
- A programmer can write C or C++ code that concatenates byte fragments consisting of meaningful machine code into a byte buffer, and then emit a call to the start of this machine code fragment. Typically, the machine code fragment contains one or more return statements that will return control to the calling C/C++ code.
- However, because most C and C++ programs do not make arbitrary jumps, when these programs are executed under an Operating System (OS), the OS may use a CPU feature known as "Execution Disable bit" (NX) to prevent jumps into addresses that were not part of the C/C++ compiler's binary output.
- Typically, the "function pointer" feature is used by C programmers to implement a [Virtual method table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).
- C++ provides a more human-understandable mechanism for creating inheritable class objects, which is achieved in part by the virtual method table mechanism.
- The difference between the C and C++ approach to virtual method table is that,

  1. In C, the programmer has to take care of all manipulations needed to maintain the virtual method table;
  2. In C, the programmer is allowed to make all kinds of manipulations to the virtual method table, at any time (even in the middle of a method's execution)

---

- Typically, polymorphic engines (code obfuscation) do not make use of virtual method table. This is because a hard-coded virtual method table is highly visible when the machine code is analyzed at run-time (with a debugger attached), because they consist of consecutive pointers into a memory address range consisting of executable code.
- Just for learning purpose, though, it might be useful for one to implement an engine using C/C++ function pointers.

---

> I'm just looking for simple code that shows encryption/decryption
> and/or obfuscation of code using C and/or C++

Unfortunate this is out-of-topic for Programmers.StackExchange.

---

If you have questions about these topics with respect to information security:

- Encryption and decryption,
- Code obfuscation

Try ask at http://security.stackexchange.com

---

If you are looking for a C++ tool for generating callable fragments of assembly code, try [AsmJit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit). It allows one to learn the basics of programmatically generating assembly code. From this, you can learn how to generate different assembly code fragments that perform functionally equivalent computation.

(Disclaimer: I have not used AsmJit before.)